# Why ZFS spare is in use with all drives working

Tags: zfs

I have a zpool with 7 drives, 6 for raidz-2 and 1 for spare. Just now the system is suddenly off, and after restarting it shows the spare is in use, but the drives seems to be working. Also, it has a message with future date "Sat Jul 10 01:33:47 2021", which is several minutes later.

Does this mean ata-TOSHIBA_HDWD120_80E68AVAS once failed but recovered somehow? Can it be a bad cable? And should I make sdc spare again? and how?

```
  pool: mypool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 54.5G in 00:21:51 with 0 errors on Sat Jul 10 01:33:47 2021
config:

        NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        mypool                                        ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-0                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD20EZAZ-00GGJB0_WD-WXK2A60D6605  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD20EZAZ-00GGJB0_WD-WXK2A60D6ZND  ONLINE       0     0     0
            spare-2                                   ONLINE       0     0     0
              ata-TOSHIBA_HDWD120_80E68AVAS           ONLINE       0     0     0
              sdc                                     ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-TOSHIBA_HDWD120_80E65YSAS             ONLINE       0     0     0
            scsi-3600605b0059cf8f02763bc271987e6e0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            scsi-3600605b0059cf8f02763bc2719883269    ONLINE       0     0     0
        spares
          sdc                                         INUSE     currently in use

errors: No known data errors
```

Comment: try it, however check the smart values of all drives

Comment: What is the future time? The time shown is nearly 17 hours before you made this post.

Comment: The time on this site is in different timezone. I saw it was future time, but maybe I was wrong. So I'm not digging into this.

Answer (score 0):

the smart has 7 UDMA error, and both toshiba drives have a high power off retract count(193),while wd drives only have 6. But there are no bad sector. So it's almost a data/power cable problem.

after running `zpool detach mypool sdc` the pool is back to normal.

```
  pool: mypool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 54.5G in 00:21:51 with 0 errors on Sat Jul 10 01:33:47 2021
config:

        NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        mypool                                        ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-0                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD20EZAZ-00GGJB0_WD-WXK2A60D6605  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD20EZAZ-00GGJB0_WD-WXK2A60D6ZND  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-TOSHIBA_HDWD120_80E68AVAS             ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-TOSHIBA_HDWD120_80E65YSAS             ONLINE       0     0     0
            scsi-3600605b0059cf8f02763bc271987e6e0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            scsi-3600605b0059cf8f02763bc2719883269    ONLINE       0     0     0
        spares
          sdc                                         AVAIL   

errors: No known data errors
```

Thought I need to offline the drive, zero it, and add it back, but infact it's done by just one command...

The reason for future time and sudden power off is still unknown, but they are trivial t